# What PCI guidelines does a client rolling out a virtual card need to follow?

Tags: virtual, card

Clients with a virtual card program will store the PAN within an app and transmit that data via API. What guidelines will they need to adhere to? Are the virtual card numbers in the scope for PCI DSS?

Answer (score 0):

A virtual card number is still a valid card number that can be used in the same way as a card number printed on a bit of plastic.

Holding a "virtual" card number in your app is no different to holding a "real" card number in your app.

If the card number is a scheme card number (e.g. Visa, Mastercard, American Express, etc) it is 100% in scope for PCI DSS.

If it's not a scheme card number then PCI doesn't apply.